# Understanding partial section of assembly code

Tags: assembly

I have a particular section of assembly code that I must examine however I have exhausted all ends at the current point in time. Basically I have a file that has characters in it in which the previous section of the file move's characters into a temp file. After which it goes to the next section of the function which runs through the file line by line.

My question is the parts in bold are changing the character at the xor & and section but what does the eax+edx*2 part do? I dont require you to tell me exactly but could you give me an understanding of how that line works?

```
movzx   eax, byte_40E300[edx]
**xor     ecx, eax
and     ecx, 7Fh**
mov     edx, [ebp+X]
mov     eax, [ebp+B]
**mov     [eax+edx*2],cx**
```

Comment: `eax+edx*2` calculates address: take value in edx, multiply by 2, then add value in eax. This will be the memory address to store cx at

Comment: `mov     [eax+edx*2],cx` takes value of `edx` and multiplies it by two, adds value of `eax` to it, and that is used as memory address. Then it sends content of `cx` to be stored into memory at that address. (as `and ecx,0x7F` is done before, the `ch = 0` and `cl` is remaining 7 bit information of what was fetched from `40E300[edx]` memory and `xor`-ed by who-knows-what-value.

Comment: guys, please post answers as answers, not comments.

Comment: Thank you Alex and Ped7g appreciate it

Answer (score -2):

eax+edx*2 calculates address: take value in edx, multiply by 2, then add value in eax. This will be the memory address to store cx at – Alexander Zhak 1 hour ago

mov [eax+edx*2],cx takes value of edx and multiplies it by two, adds value of eax to it, and that is used as memory address. Then it sends content of cx to be stored into memory at that address. (as and ecx,0x7F is done before, the ch = 0 and cl is remaining 7 bit information of what was fetched from 40E300[edx] memory and xor-ed by who-knows-what-value. – Ped7g 1 hour ago

Comment: If you're going to steal someone's comment as an answer, at least take the time to reword it rather than just copy and paste it.  Alternatively, mark your answer as a Community Wiki, which is the appropriate thing to do when copying someone else's answer.